# Getting Silverlight Video Stream

Tags: silverlight, video, streaming

Suppose there is a Silverlight streaming video player on a random web site. How can I intercept the video stream and for example save it to file - i.e. the real source of the file.

I know some of the sites embed the source in  tag - or at least that was the case with Flash. But sometimes, players are smarter than that and call some logic via web service.  It is still possible to figure everything out by analyzing the .dll with reflector, but that is hardcore! Every player may have a different logic, so I figured out it would be easier to just get the current stream somehow.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooook! Got me an answer that could be used as a nice workaround. With the use of fiddler I was able to capture the traffic and figure out what's going on. Now I'm happily watchin the same video as before only using the uber feature of WMP that lets me play videos faster.